# Ajax Based search PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to create an AJAX based search in PHP. The code I have written so far does not seem to be working uptil now. Any suggesstions would be of great help. Thanks in advance. Here is my code.

index.php

```
<head>
<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" name="text" id="text" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)"/>


<div id="inner"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function showHint(str) {
        if(str.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = "search";
            return;
        }

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlhttpreadystate == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("REQUEST", "search.php?text"+str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

search.php

```
<?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $password= 'root';
    $db = 'demo';

    @$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db, $conn);

    /*if($result) {
        echo "success";
    } else { echo "fail"; }
    */



$text = $_REQUEST['text'];
$text = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $text);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users where first_name LIKE '%$text%' OR last_name LIKE '%$text%'";

$action = mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_num_rows($action);

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($action)) {
  $output .= $res['first_name']. ' '.$res['last_name'];
  echo $output;
}


?>
```

Comment: Define "not working". Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the equal sign in the script(after the text) in index.php.

xmlhttp.open("REQUEST", "search.php?text="+str, true);

Answer (score 0):

Why you are doing this lengthy process, You can also try this jQuery ajax,

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'search.php',
      type: 'GET',
      data: 'text='+str,
      success: function(data) {
        //called when successful
        $('#inner').html(data);
      },
      error: function(e) {
        //called when there is an error
        console.log(e.message);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just getting the input in search.php. Can you try these codes:

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)"/>
<div id="inner"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getHttpRequest()
{
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
return xmlhttp;
}
function showHint(str)
{
var xmlhttp; 
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = "search";
            return;
  }

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {   
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
                document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }  
xmlhttp.open("GET", "search.php?str="+str, true);

xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

search.php:

```
<?php
$text=$_GET["str"];
echo $text;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'search.php',
      type: 'GET',
      data: 'text='+str,
      success: function(data) {
        //called when successful
        $('#inner').html(data);
      },
      error: function(e) {
        //called when there is an error
        console.log(e.message);  
    alert(e.message); // if you dont know how to check console
      }
    });
```